# how can get the numbers between each operator in a single textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim result As Double
    Dim plus As String()
    Dim Substract As String()
    Dim multiply As String()
    Dim divide As String()
    Dim powerto As String()
    Dim num As Long

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("^") Then
        powerto = TextBox1.Text.Split("^")
        For Each NumToPower As String In powerto
            result = System.Math.Pow(NumToPower, powerto.Length)
            ' num ^= CStr(NumToPower)
        Next
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("/") Then
        divide = TextBox1.Text.Split("/")
        For Each numbertodivide As String In divide
            If numbertodivide <> 0 Then
                num /= CStr(numbertodivide)
                result = num
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Divide By 0")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("*") Then
        multiply = TextBox1.Text.Split("*")
        For Each NumToPower As String In multiply
            num *= CStr(NumToPower)
        Next
        result = num
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("+") Then
        plus = TextBox1.Text.Split("+")
        For Each NumToPower As String In plus
            num += CStr(NumToPower)

        Next
        result = num
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("-") Then
        Substract = TextBox1.Text.Split("-")
        For Each NumToPower As String In Substract
            num -= CStr(NumToPower)
        Next
        result = num
    End If

    MessageBox.Show(result)
```

I have one TextBox, and written in it for example " 15*2^3" how can I get each number in this equation, before calculating it?

Comment: when input is ` " 15*2^3"` then you want the output as 1,5,2,3 or 15,2,3? or the whole numbers as a string? 1523?

Comment: i want the output as 15,2,3 @NeethuSoman

Comment: I added some codes.so you can try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim input As String = "15*2^35"  
    Dim digits() As String = Regex.Split(input, "[^0-9]+") 
    For Each item As String In digits
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
```

But in you case It is better to implement tokenizer

Full grammar for your case is

```
<exp> ::= <exp> + <term> | <exp> - <term> | <term>
<term> ::= <term> * <power> | <term> / <power> | <power>
<power> ::= <factor> ^ <power> | <factor>
<factor> ::= ( <exp> ) | <int>
<int> ::= <digit> <int> | <digit>
<digit> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

For simple equations `" +-*/ and ( ) "` you can try my simple naive solution. Note that I am not good at parsers or grammars So I used simple ready grammar with left recursion removed.

```
Simple arithmetic grammar, with left recursion removed, is
expression → factor E’
E’ → + factor E’ | - factor E’ | ε
factor → term F’
F’ → * term F’ | / term F’ | ε
term → digit | ( expression )
digit → 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Here is simple code for doing it:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim input() = {"---9+6", "5+6*9+8", "6---9", "15+7*9-(7*9)", "8*9+8*9/3+5", "15*8+5", "15+(8*5)"}
        For Each m As String In input
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", m, calculate(m))
        Next
        Dim st = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(calculate(st))
        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub


    Dim numbers As New List(Of Double)

    Public Function calculate(ByVal expression As String) As String
        Try
            numbers.Clear()

            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression) Then
                Return ""
            End If 
            Dim index = 0
            Exp(expression, index)

            If numbers.Count > 0 Then
                Return numbers(0).ToString()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

        End Try
        Return ""
    End Function

    Private Sub Exp(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        '; E -> FE’ 
        factor(expression, index)
        primeops(expression, index)

    End Sub

    Private Sub primeops(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        '; E’ -> + F E’ | - F E’ | e
        Select Case getChr(expression, index)

            Case "+"
                index += 1
                '   E() ' -> + F E’  
                factor(expression, index)
                If numbers.Count >= 2 Then
                    Dim at = numbers.Count - 1
                    numbers(at - 1) = numbers(at - 1) + numbers(at)
                    numbers.RemoveAt(at)
                End If
                primeops(expression, index)
            Case "-"
                index += 1
                '   E() ' -> - F E’ 
                factor(expression, index)
                If numbers.Count >= 2 Then
                    Dim at = numbers.Count - 1
                    numbers(at - 1) = numbers(at - 1) - numbers(at)
                    numbers.RemoveAt(at)
                End If
                primeops(expression, index)
            Case ")"
                index += 1
            Case Else
                '; E’ -> e

        End Select
    End Sub
    Private Sub factor(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        '; F -> TF’
        t(expression, index)
        fprime(expression, index)
    End Sub





    Private Sub fprime(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        '; F -> * T F’ | / T F’ | e
        Select Case getChr(expression, index)
            Case "*"
                index += 1
                '; F -> * T F’ 
                t(expression, index)

                If numbers.Count >= 2 Then
                    Dim at = numbers.Count - 1
                    numbers(at - 1) = numbers(at - 1) * numbers(at)
                    numbers.RemoveAt(at)
                End If
                fprime(expression, index)
            Case "/"
                index += 1
                '; F ->  / T F’  
                t(expression, index)
                If numbers.Count >= 2 Then
                    Dim at = numbers.Count - 1
                    numbers(at - 1) = numbers(at - 1) / numbers(at)
                    numbers.RemoveAt(at)
                End If
                fprime(expression, index)

            Case ")"
                index += 1
        End Select
        '; F ->  e 
    End Sub



    Private Sub t(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        'T -> G | (E) 
        number(expression, index)
        brackets(expression, index)
    End Sub


    Private Sub brackets(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        skipspace(expression, index)
        If getChr(expression, index) = "(" Then
            index += 1
            Exp(expression, index)
        End If
        skipspace(expression, index)
    End Sub

    Private Sub number(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        'numbers +-[0-9]+.[0-9]+

        skipspace(expression, index)

        Dim sign As Integer = 1
        While True
            If getChr(expression, index) = "+" Then
                index += 1
            ElseIf getChr(expression, index) = "-" Then
                index += 1
                sign = -sign
            Else
                Exit While

            End If

        End While

        Dim m = index
        While Char.IsDigit(getChr(expression, index))
            index += 1
        End While
        If index > m Then
            If getChr(expression, index) = "." Then
                index += 1
                While Char.IsDigit(getChr(expression, index))
                    index += 1
                End While
            End If
            Dim str = expression.Substring(m, index - m)
            numbers.Add(sign * Double.Parse(str)) 
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub skipspace(ByVal expression As String, ByRef index As Integer)
        While Char.IsWhiteSpace(getChr(expression, index))
            index += 1
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Function getChr(ByVal Expressions As String, index As Integer) As Char
        If index > Expressions.Length - 1 Then
            Return ""  '
        End If
        Return Expressions(index)

    End Function


End Module
```

Output:

```
---9+6 -> -3
5+6*9+8 -> 67
6---9 -> -3
15+7*9-(7*9) -> 15
8*9+8*9/3+5 -> 101
15*8+5 -> 125
15+(8*5) -> 55
```

Comment: thank you for your help i am a beginner in vb.net. My objective is to calculate all this equation and to do that i have to start with 
"2^35" and its result multiply it by 15. do you have an idea how can i accomplish it according to mycode? Thank you again !

Comment: if you want to do this task by yourself you should be familiar with grammars( for example BNF).then write your own tokenizer and parser for evaluating expression

Comment: There's no need for all that.  Simply pass the expression to the DLR and get the result.  @gew this problem has been solved many times by many people - and reggae and tokenizing is at the bottom of that list.  Do some research.

Comment: I posted code for doing such task. but note that it is not tested well. plus if you want power you should add it. cause I did not implement it